# equivalent command of OUTER APPLY in MS access 2016

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2016

I've tried to relate to tables in order to get new information but it seems like there is no OUTER APPLY in MS access. Here is my code:

```
    SELECT *
FROM [pred-predi_calculo-presi]
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP 1 [snptc_histo].POSICIONBUS
      FROM [snptc_histo]
      WHERE [snptc_histo].PATENTEBUS = [pred-predi_calculo-presi].PATENTE
        AND [snptc_histo].horaConsulta < [pred-predi_calculo-presi].'pasadaReal'
      ORDER BY [snptc_histo].horaConsulta DESC
    ) AS p
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT TOP 1 [snptc_histo].POSICIONBUS
      FROM [snptc_histo]
      WHERE [snptc_histo].PATENTEBUS = [pred-predi_calculo-presi].PATENTE
        AND [snptc_histo].horaConsulta >= [pred-predi_calculo-presi].'pasadaReal'
      ORDER BY [snptc_histo].horaConsulta ASC
    ) AS n ;
```

Any help will be well received

Edit: I'd thought it'd be much easier to do this action with java code (I have the algorithm in mind) and also more optimal, but I don't have the right tools like data structures or right "commands" to work with databases throw java (I'm mathematician) so to do this in java I'd need much more help. Although I'm open to comments about this solution.
Here's a sample data:

pred-predi_calculo-presi:

```
Id1 ID                       Paradero'horaPrediccion''pasadaReal'PREDICCION_NUEVA   PATENTE servicio
1   2016-12-13 11:36:50_T518    PA52    11:36:51       11:36:20      1579,242       CJRW-73    518
2   2016-12-13 11:36:50_T518    PA52    11:36:51       11:36:20      761,211        BJFB-79    518
3   2016-12-13 12:11:02_T518    PC475   12:17:53       12:16:34      1382,545       BFKC-47    518
4   2016-12-13 12:11:02_T518    PC475   12:17:53       12:16:34      695,283        CJRW-74    518
5   2016-12-13 12:11:03_T418    PC206   12:16:27       12:15:50      1210,033       ZN-6742    418
6   2016-12-13 12:11:03_T418    PC206   12:16:27       12:15:50      1407,741       ZN-5814    418
7   2016-12-13 13:16:41_T516    PD208   13:17:56       13:18:02      842,634        BJFY-17    516
```

snptc_histo:

```
PATENTEBUS  POSICIONBUS horaConsulta
WA-9114     0           17:15:52
CJRW-83     3,64        17:15:52
ZN-3967     0,26        17:15:50
BJFV-89     11,06       17:15:51
BJFS-92     32,866      17:15:51
FLXJ-30     19,74       17:15:51
BJFR-52     9,55        17:15:50
CJRW-52     24,67       17:15:50
BJFR-94     14,75       17:15:49
CJRT-63     16,02       17:15:49
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the easiest thing to do in Access, but try the following.

Query1 - intermediate query to find the max horaConsulta value less than pasadaReal for each PATENTEBUS value:

```
SELECT s.PATENTEBUS, MAX(horaConsulta) AS MaxHoraConsulta
FROM [snptc_histo] AS s 
INNER JOIN [pred-predi_calculo-presi] AS p ON s.PATENTEBUS = p.PATENTE
WHERE s.horaConsulta < p.pasadaReal
GROUP BY s.PATENTEBUS
```

Query2 - use Query1 to find the associated POSICIONBUS value:

```
SELECT s.PATENTEBUS, s.POSICIONBUS
FROM [snptc_histo] AS s 
INNER JOIN Query1 AS q ON s.PATENTEBUS = q.PATENTEBUS AND s.horaConsulta = q.MaxHoraConsulta
```

Now create similar queries to find the min horaConsulta value greater than or equal to pasadaReal for each PATENTEBUS value, and its associated POSICIONBUS value:

Query3

```
SELECT s.PATENTEBUS, MIN(horaConsulta) AS MinHoraConsulta
FROM [snptc_histo] AS s 
INNER JOIN [pred-predi_calculo-presi] AS p ON s.PATENTEBUS = p.PATENTE
WHERE s.horaConsulta >= p.pasadaReal
GROUP BY s.PATENTEBUS
```

Query4

```
SELECT s.PATENTEBUS, s.POSICIONBUS
FROM [snptc_histo] AS s 
INNER JOIN Query3 AS q ON s.PATENTEBUS = q.PATENTEBUS AND s.horaConsulta = q.MinHoraConsulta
```

Now your final query becomes:

```
SELECT p.*, q2.POSICIONBUS, q4.POSICIONBUS
FROM ([pred-predi_calculo-presi] AS p
LEFT JOIN Query2 AS q2 ON p.PATENTE = q2.PATENTEBUS)
LEFT JOIN Query4 AS q4 ON p.PATENTE = q4.PATENTEBUS
```

Comment: Query1 doesn't work; looks like "WHERE s.horaConsulta < p.pasadaReal" ask for a value of p.pasadaReal as WHERE acts on SELECT

Comment: So what is `[pred-predi_calculo-presi].'pasadaReal'` in your original post? I assumed that this should have been written as `[pred-predi_calculo-presi].[pasadaReal]`, in other words I assumed that `pasadaReal` is a column in the `[pred-predi_calculo-presi]` table. Is this wrong?

Comment: right, but as I said, WHERE acts on SELECT, so it sees [snptc_histo] columns in the row it's writing, not columns from other table 'cause it doesn't know which row to see

Comment: WHERE can act on JOIN also. I recreated minimal table structure based on your original post and this query worked as expected. Can you post your table structures and sample data?

Comment: I added sample data

Comment: Hmmm, can you show the table design view for table `pred-predi_calculo-presi`. Do the column names `'horaPrediccion'` and `'pasadaReal'` in design view have the single quotes around them? If so, you could try adding the single quotes into my queries. Also, your original post mentions `[snptc_histo].horaConsulta` but I do not see this column in your sample data.